# How to change label text every x seconds with a timer

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, timer, controls

I want to update the Text of a label in my form every 5000 ms, I've been trying to use a timer, but it doesn't work and I don't know why. This is the code I am using:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    openRequests();

    System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    aTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
    aTimer.Interval = 20000;
    aTimer.Enabled = true;
}
private  void  OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    codeComboBox.Items.Clear();
    try
    {
        connectionDB.Open();
        String query = "";
        query = "SELECT GMKEY0 FROM SAM_FILNAS.EGESM1F0 WHERE GMSTX0 = '0' OR GMSTX0 = 'P' ";
        daMAT = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connectionDB);
        dsMAT = new System.Data.DataSet();
        daMAT.Fill(dsMAT, "sam_filnas.EGESM1F0 ");
        foreach (System.Data.DataTable t in dsMAT.Tables)
        {
            foreach (System.Data.DataRow r in t.Rows)
            {
                codeComboBox.Items.Add(r["GMKEY0"]);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("non riesco a scaricare le richieste di manutenzione aperte");
    }
    label7.Text = "CI SONO " + codeComboBox.Items.Count.ToString() + " RICHIESTE DI MANUTENZIONE";
    connectionDB.Close();
    //updateTimer.Start();
    resertAllTheControls();
}
```

The timer starts and every 5 seconds the `onTimeEvent` method is called, but for some reason it seems that the execution of the method stops at  `codeComboBox.Items.Clear();`

Please, explain to me why this happens.

Comment: Does it works if you delete `codeComboBox.Items.Clear();`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `System.Timers.Timer`. Use [`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=netframework-4.8) instead.

The `Elapsed` executes on a ThreadPool thread, meaning you will have to use `Invoke` when attempting to change things on the UI, because the UI has it own thread.

`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`'s `Tick` event occurs on the UI thread, so there is no need for any special code to work with UI elements in it's event handler.

The `System.Timers.Timer` use `System.Threading.Timer` internally. 
From the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#remarks) paragraph of the `System.Threading.Timer` documentation page:

> `System.Threading.Timer` is a simple, lightweight timer that uses callback methods and is served by thread pool threads.
>   It is not recommended for use with Windows Forms, because its callbacks do not occur on the user interface thread.
>   `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` is a better choice for use with Windows Forms.